# Spring creating a bean dependant on other beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have the following class

```
public class ConnectionPool {

@Autowired
private Properties props;

@Autowired
private Key internalKey;

public ConnectionPool{
   System.out.println(internalKey);
   System.out.println(props);
}
}
```

I am creating the ConnectionPool class as a bean in the following way in a class called ApplicationConfig.

```
@Bean
ConnectionPool returnConnectionPool(){
    ConnectionPool cPool = new ConnectionPool();
    return cPool;
}
```

In the ApplicationConfig class I also have

```
@Bean
Properties returnAppProperties()
{
   Properties props = new Properties();
   return props;
}

@Bean 
Key returnInternalKey()
{
  Key key = new Key();
  return key;
}
```

Why does

```
   System.out.println(internalKey);
   System.out.println(props);
```

print null when the Spring mvc app is starting? I thought Spring took care of all the bean instantiation and injection? What else do I have to do?

Comment: Yes it is   `@Configuration public class ApplicationConfig {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problems is

```
@Bean
ConnectionPool returnConnectionPool(){
    ConnectionPool cPool = new ConnectionPool();
    return cPool;
}
```

You are not letting spring autowire the dependencies inside the ConnectionPool class as you are explicitly creating it using new construct.

To make it work I would suggest you to have a constructor which take both the dependencies and then change your returnConnectionPool method to look like this

```
@Bean
ConnectionPool returnConnectionPool(Properties properties, Key key){
    ConnectionPool cPool = new ConnectionPool(properties, key);
    return cPool;
}
```

(P.S. this is just one of the possible solution but spring has a lot of other magical ways to do the same stuff :) )